# How do I validate this regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

```
<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(XXX)XXX-XXXX" type="tel"
       pattern="^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$" required="true"/>
```

How can I validate if that pattern is used in JavaScript for browsers that don't support the pattern attribute?

Thank you for your input -- I've tried doing several options below, but I can't seem to get anything to trace out as "true" -- the RegExp works in the HTML pattern field for FireFox and Chrome. But it's always returning false when I'm trying to utilize it with javaScript?

http://pastebin.com/M0Pdn2Z3

Comment: Handle `change` event, get `pattern` attribute, run regex. In which part have you encountered problems? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of [polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) that will enable this in older browsers:

- [nwxforms](https://github.com/dperini/nwxforms), no dependencies
- [HTML5 Form Shim](https://github.com/dsheiko/HTML5-Form-Shim), requires jQuery
- [h5Validate](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/), also requires jQuery

I'd recommend polyfilling -- this doesn't change the behavior for modern browsers but emulates it in old ones. (An aside: the [Modernizr polyfills list](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) is fantastic.)

You could also write it yourself; some other answers show how that's done.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `onchange` event that reads the `pattern` attribute and runs it against the `value`.

```
// Only bind event if we need to
if(!('pattern' in document.createElement('input'))){
    // Bind the event
    document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('change', function(){
        // Get the regex and value then test it
        var regex = new RegExp(this.pattern),
            val = this.value,
            valid = regex.test(val);

        // Is it valid?
        if(!valid){
            // Do something when it's not
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate when submitting the form, or losing focus from the input.

If you use jQuery, this will work for all elements with `pattern` attribute:

```
$('[pattern]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val().match($(this).attr('pattern')))
        alert('Bad value');
});
```

If not, you can do something for this (similar):

```
var inputs = getElementsByName('input');
for (var index in inputs) {
    var input = inputs[index];
    var pattern = input.getAttribute('pattern');
    if (pattern != '' && pattern != null) {
        if (!input.value.match(pattern))
            alert('Bad value');
    }
}
```

These will loop through the attributes that have a pattern to identify against, check them, and alert the user if there's a problem. 
Of course, you can change the alert to whatever way you would like to handle it (for example, return false to cancel the form submission).

I haven't tested this code, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) or add `onchange` event to your input.

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('change', function(){\
    // returns true if input matches regexp, otherwise it returns false
    var isValid = RegExp(this.pattern).test(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var regex = /^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/;
    if(phone.value.match(regex)){
        console.log('true');
    }else{
        console.log('false');
    }
```

I just ended up using this... It worked. @_@